# How to run Python Library Module as a script from another python file? (Python 3.5.1)

Tags: python

I am currently running a python file I created as a library module as a script and passing in one command line argument More specifically, the way I am running a python file now is

`python3 -m path.to.python.file --option1=OPTION_VALUE`

I actually have several of these files and I want to run them all from a different python file. How would I do this? If it makes it easier the value of the `option1` argument is the same for all of them.

I have seen many other StackOverflow posts regarding similar issues but none of them seem to be about running a python file as a library module as a script.

EDIT: I think I found an answer. I ended up doing the following:

```
    p = subprocess.Popen(['python3', '-m',
                          'path.to.file',
                          '--option1=OPTION1_VALUE'])
    p.communicate()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use `subprocess` and just run them all as separate programs:

```
subprocess.Popen(['python3', '-m', 'path.to.python.file', '--option1=OPTION_VALUE'])
```

This *might* not be the best way to do it.  Depending on how the modules are structured, you might be able to `import` them and call some of the functions within (which is what is happening from the commandline).  However, without seeing the structure of those modules, it's hard to give clear advice on how you might do that.

Comment: Great! This almost works for me. So the reason why this doesn't exactly fit my use case is that I want to basically run a bunch of files in order. Some are SQL scripts and some are Python files (Both ultimately create tables in a Database. For the python files I use sqlalchemy/pandas). I want to be able to run these files in a particular order. It seems like when I use `subprocess.Popen` it always runs the Python files at the end. Is there a way for me to do this but be able to run the files in order?